# What are the distinctions between "authoritarian", "totalitarian", and "dictatorial"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

I'm giving a talk about technology (specifically the Internet) in various governments where freedoms are strongly constrained.  I'm a technologist, and I have little experience with words used to described the governments of places like Cuba, China, Iran, N. Korea, Libya, etc.

I've learned from reading new articles that these governments are variously described as "totalitarian," "authoritarian," "autocractic," "despotic," "dictatorial," and so forth, and I've inferred that these are all essentially equivalent.  Of course I'm anxious at the prospect of using them as synonyms if there are well-agreed-upon differences that I should be aware of.  My web searches haven't really helped in my quest to answer this question and so I thought I'd ask you folks if you feel there are strong differences.

In particular, are there any terms in my list above you feel have strong differential meanings?

**Note**: A search here on English.SE shows two related questions both closed without an answer, so I'm hoping that my question is clear (and polite) enough to avoid this fate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These words are related but might not refer to the same exact thing. For example if you check the Wikipedia entry for [Authoritarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarianism) you will find this entry:

> Authoritarianism is a form of social
>   organization characterized by
>   submission to authority. It is opposed
>   to individualism and democracy. In
>   politics, an authoritarian government
>   is one in which political power is
>   concentrated in a leader or leaders,
>   typically unelected by the people, who
>   possess exclusive, unaccountable, and
>   arbitrary power. Authoritarianism
>   differs from [totalitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarianism) in that
>   social and economic institutions exist
>   that are not under the government's
>   control.

so immediately you see the distinction between authoritarianism vs. totalitarianism. If you now go to the Wikipedia entry for [Totalitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarianism) you will find this entry:

> Totalitarianism (or totalitarian rule)
>   is a political system where the state,
>   usually under the power of a single
>   political person, faction, or class,
>   recognizes no limits to its authority
>   and strives to regulate every aspect
>   of public and private life wherever
>   feasible.Totalitarianism is
>   usually characterized by the
>   coincidence of [authoritarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarianism) (where
>   ordinary citizens have less
>   significant share in state
>   decision-making) and ideology (a
>   pervasive scheme of values promulgated
>   by institutional means to direct most
>   if not all aspects of public and of public and private life).

We see here that Totalitarianism is characterized by Authoritarianism  AND ideology.

If we now check [Despotism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Despotism) vs. [Dictatorship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship) we find that for Despotism is

> a form of government in which a single
>   entity, called the despot, rules with
>   absolute power. That entity may be an
>   individual, as in an autocracy, or it
>   may be a group, as in an oligarchy.
>   The word despotism means to "rule in
>   the fashion of a despot" and should
>   not be confused with "despot", an
>   individual.

the key word here is "single entity" which can actually be an individual OR a group. Under [dictatorship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship) we find this entry:

> A dictatorship is defined as an
>   autocratic form of government in which
>   the government is ruled by an
>   individual, the dictator.

also we find the distinction between dictatorships and totalitarian rule (with reference to authoritarianism:

> For some scholars, a dictatorship is a
>   form of government that has the power
>   to govern without consent of those
>   being governed (similar to
>   authoritarianism), while
>   totalitarianism describes a state that
>   regulates nearly every aspect of
>   public and private behavior of the
>   people. In other words, dictatorship
>   concerns the source of the governing
>   power (where the power comes from) and
>   totalitarianism concerns the scope of
>   the governing power (what is the
>   government). In this sense,
>   dictatorship (government without
>   people's consent) is a contrast to
>   democracy (government whose power
>   comes from people) and totalitarianism
>   (government controls every aspect of
>   people's life) opposes pluralism
>   (government allows multiple lifestyles
>   and opinions). Though the definitions
>   of the terms differ, they are related
>   in reality as most of the dictatorship
>   states tend to show totalitarian
>   characteristics. When governments'
>   power does not come from the people,
>   their power is not limited and tend to
>   expand their scope of power to control
>   every aspect of people's life.

For [autocracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocracy) we find this entry:

> An autocracy is a form of government
>   in which one person possesses
>   unlimited power.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarianism) An autocrat is a
>   person (such as a monarch) ruling with
>   unlimited authority.

a distinction is made between autocratic rule vs. miliatry dictatorships with some reference also to totalitarian rule:

> Autocracy and totalitarianism are
>   related concepts. Autocracy is defined
>   by one individual having unlimited
>   legislative and executive power, while
>   totalitarianism extends to regulating
>   every aspect of public and private
>   life. Totalitarianism does not imply a
>   single ruler, but extends to include
>   absolute rule by any faction or class
>   of elites who recognize no limit to
>   their authority. Autocracy differs
>   from military dictatorship, as these
>   often take the form of "collective
>   presidencies" such as the South
>   American juntas. However, an autocracy
>   may be totalitarian or be a military
>   dictatorship.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I give the edge to The Raven's answer because it is more succinct and perhaps more accessible.  However, ideally people would use both answers, as they are complementary.

Comment: How does "monarchy" fit here? Isn't "monarchy" identical to "autocracy"?

Answer (score 10):

To give some real-world examples, we could posit the following as exemplars (understanding, of course, that these characterizations are subject to debate):

- Authoritarian state: Singapore
- Totalitarian state: Maoist China (particularly during the Cultural Revolution)
- Despotic state: Uganda under Idi Amin; Zimbabwe under Mugabe
- Dictatorship: Italy under Mussolini, Egypt under Mubarak
- Autocracy: Libya under Qaddafi

While we usually hold negative associations about these kinds of regimes, in some cases like Suharto's long authoritarian rule of Indonesia, we see stability and a general improvement in the citizens' standard of living.

Comment: I think this is a somewhat tricky question to answer, and making use of examples is a very good strategy here.  Maybe some people will disagree with your characterizations, and maybe some people won't know enough about the countries mentioned, but at least if they *do*, this answer will be more helpful and quicker to grasp than pageman's (which provides some nice information, but is long and technical).

Comment: @John Y: Thank you. I liked pageman's response and rec'd it. However, some examples did seem to be in order for clarity's sake. It is tricky because few regimes are wholly one type or another.

Comment: Can you explain what characteristics make (say) Qaddafi an autocrat rather than a despot?  Are these examples well-accepted, or more from personal opinion?

Comment: Neither these examples nor the current accepted answer really illustrate any difference between dictator and despot that I can grasp.

Answer (score 6):

“Authoritarian” is best understood by considering where authority/the power rests. Is it with the government/state? Or does it sit with the individual?  The opposite of “authoritarianism” is “liberty”. You may have countless forms of government that support one side or the other, or anywhere along the spectrum between the two.

That said, totalitarianism is an extreme form of authoritarianism, implying total control over all affairs. "Despotic" is the degree to which those in control are willing to go to enforce their authoritarianism, often implying terrorizing the populace, even arbitrarily,  as a means of gaining compliance/achieving those in power's desired ends (which may be as base as pure, morbid self-gratification, etc.).

That aside, a *dictatorship* (generally synonymous with autocracy) is a form of government — as are *democracy, monarchy, anarchy* (classic definition, not the "hoodlums busting windows chanting anti-capitalist/pro-commie slogans" pop-media usage), *theocracy*, etc.

Any one of these forms of government can tilt towards liberty or authoritarianism.

For example, a dictator might be a despot and deem that the nation he rules is for his personal agenda only, that people are there to serve his interest (financing it through taxes, for example), the populace essentially slaves to his whim, his national interests, etc. He and his cronies may rape and pillage and terrorize, their own populations etc. as a means of gaining compliance or/and personal gratification.

Or… the dictator may deem that liberty is the highest social order, and that the sole purpose of his government is to restore the population's liberty — their right to consent. He would jail those who would steal, murder, etc., and while he would encourage the to be charitable and good people, and otherwise leave them alone. The people would be responsible for funding the forces used to protect their own liberty, and would be free to organize that as they choose.  He would probably come down on hard against those who would choose to politically organize to create a form of government that enables the violation of the individual's right to consent/liberty.  In other words, the people are able to do as they please so long as they respect others' liberty — their right to say "no thanks" when it comes to their property, body, labor, etc.  They may have no say in their government, but their government only intervenes to protect them. It is otherwise non existent.  This is unlikely, but it is conceivable.

With that in mind, totalitarian quantifies the degree of which authoritarianism reigns. E.g. a democracy may lean quite heavily to authoritarian rule — where the majority may violate the liberty of others who lose elections. The more the people vote that individuals must defer to the State authority on all matters, the more totalitarian the authoritarian government.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. A dictator that requires liberty. It brings some  current-day movements to mind :p