# Single noun for someone who claims authority

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that describes not only people who are granted authority by others (leader), but anyone who claims it, regardless of whether they receive it from others. In particular, religious authority, but it doesn't need to be limited to that.
Thank you!

Comment: *Usurper* comes to mind but it comes with the implication of taking authority by means of force. I assume you're looking for a more general term.

Comment: Maybe Alexander Haig?

Comment: Poseur or self-important.

Comment: Closely related: [What are the distinctions between authoritarian, totalitarian and dictator{ial?}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22477/what-are-the-distinctions-between-authoritarian-totalitarian-and-dictator/22478#22478). _Autocratic_ works.

Comment: A demagogue would be one.

Comment: Number two in command, or commander.

Comment: You have used the Single-word-request tag, this tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Answer (score -1):

You can use authoritarian as a noun or you could use autocrat

Comment: This falls below the standard expected here, of providing cited/linked dictionary definitions for suggested words.

Answer (score -1):

I'm focusing on the religious bent of the question.

1. theocrat
2. cleric
3. vicar
4. magus
5. theologian
6. hierophant
7. priest
8. monk
9. prophet
10. saint

Comment: This falls below the standard expected here, of providing cited/linked dictionary definitions for suggested words.

Comment: @AndyT Cite something.